# scp command - transfer folder over ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a Arduino Yun and want setup the server for Yun.

So what I want is to copy a folder that contain a py file and a index.html to my Yun

I used mac terminal to do this operation

the command looks like this

```
scp -r /Users/gudi/Desktop/LobsterHeartRate root@192.168.240.1:/mnt/sda1
```

and then terminal asked for the password

after I typed, it shows

```
scp: /mnt/sda1/LobsterHeartRate: Not a directory
```

I didn't type /mnt/sda1/LobsterHeartRate  why it shows this error

Comment: But it shows `LobsterHeartRate` in your `scp` command. Your question is very unclear, to say the least.

Comment: you have it in your source; you need to either create the dir in your target or specify file(s) [/Users/gudi/Desktop/LobsterHeartRate/*] in your source

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
scp -r /Users/gudi/Desktop/LobsterHeartRate root@192.168.240.1:/mnt/sda1
```

requires that the remote directory `/mnt/sda1` exists. This looks like it is not true in your case. Check it using `ssh root@192.168.240.1 ls /mnt/sda1`.

`scp` is simple tool and it does not allow you to rename directories on the fly and the target directory must exists. You might try

```
scp -r /Users/gudi/Desktop/LobsterHeartRate root@192.168.240.1:/mnt/
ssh root@192.168.240.1 mv /mnt/LobsterHeartRate /mnt/sda1
```

or so, if it will suit your needs. But copying more files, `rsync` is usually more suitable. Check its manual page and give it a try next time.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jens Höpken notes, your post is a bit sparse. But trying to read between the lines of your post I suspect that LobsterHeartRate is a DIRECTORY on your local system but a FILE named LobsterHeartRate in your target system. This might be happening right at the top of the directory tree, or perhaps you have directories/files of the same name further down the tree. scp -rv might help resolve any confusions here.

***Beware:*** scp -r resolves symbolic links. If you want to preserve symlinks you need to do something else. For historic reasons I use the following, though **cpio** with a **find** front-end opens up interesting possibilities for fine-grained file selections.

```
  ( cd /Users/gudi/Desktop && tar -cf - LobsterHeartRate ) |
      ssh root@192.168.240.1 'cd /mnt/sda1 && tar -xf -'
```

For a safe "dry run" you could change the -xf to a -tf. The && chains are required to prevent bad things from happening if any prior command fails.

Disclaimer: any debugging is left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, I tried your code on mac terminal. It now shows ` tar: can't create directory 'LobsterHeartRate' :File exits ` and ` tar: can't remove old file LobsterHeartRate/ ._.DS_Store: Not a directory` Do you mind tell me what these means   Thanks a lot

Comment: and when i use tf instead of xf, it shows `LobsterHeartRate/
  LobsterHeartRate/._.DS_Store
  LobsterHeartRate/.DS_Store
  LobsterHeartRate/templates/
  LobsterHeartRate/._Measuring.py
  LobsterHeartRate/Measruing.py
  LobsterHeartRate/templates/._index.html
  LobsterHeartRate/remplates/index.html `

Comment: This makes me wonder what entries exist, and don't exist, on both systems.  [1] On local, try ( cd /Users/gudi/Desktop && ls -l  ) to check LobsterHeartRate there. Then ssh root@192.168.240.1 'namei /mnt/sda1/LobsterHeartRate' to check out paths on the target system.